# Why do you need to include a field in GROUP BY when using OVER (PARTITION BY x)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a table for which I want to do a simple sum of a field, grouped by two columns. I then want the total for all values for each year_num.

**See example: http://rextester.com/QSLRS68794**

This query is throwing: "42803: column "foo.num_cust" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function", and I cannot figure out why. **Why would an aggregate function using the OVER (PARTITION BY x) require the summed field to be in GROUP BY??**

```
select 
    year_num
    ,age_bucket
    ,sum(num_cust)
    --,sum(num_cust) over (partition by year_num)  --THROWS ERROR!!
from
    foo
group by
    year_num
    ,age_bucket
order by 1,2
```

**TABLE:**

```
| loc_id |  year_num |  gen |  cust_category |  cust_age |  num_cust |  age_bucket |
|--------|-----------|------|----------------|-----------|-----------|-------------|
| 1      | 2016      | M    | cash           | 41        | 2         | 04_<45      |
| 1      | 2016      | F    | Prepaid        | 41        | 1         | 03_<35      |
| 1      | 2016      | F    | cc             | 61        | 1         | 05_45+      |
| 1      | 2016      | F    | cc             | 19        | 2         | 02_<25      |
| 1      | 2016      | M    | cc             | 64        | 1         | 05_45+      |
| 1      | 2016      | F    | cash           | 46        | 1         | 05_45+      |
| 1      | 2016      | F    | cash           | 27        | 3         | 03_<35      |
| 1      | 2016      | M    | cash           | 42        | 1         | 04_<45      |
| 1      | 2017      | F    | cc             | 35        | 1         | 04_<45      |
| 1      | 2017      | F    | cc             | 37        | 1         | 04_<45      |
| 1      | 2017      | F    | cash           | 46        | 1         | 05_45+      |
| 1      | 2016      | F    | cash           | 19        | 4         | 02_<25      |
| 1      | 2017      | M    | cash           | 43        | 1         | 04_<45      |
| 1      | 2017      | M    | cash           | 29        | 1         | 03_<35      |
| 1      | 2016      | F    | cc             | 13        | 1         | 01_<18      |
| 1      | 2017      | F    | cash           | 16        | 2         | 01_<18      |
| 1      | 2016      | F    | cc             | 17        | 2         | 01_<18      |
| 1      | 2016      | M    | cc             | 17        | 2         | 01_<18      |
| 1      | 2017      | F    | cash           | 18        | 9         | 02_<25      |
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
| year_num | age_bucket | sum | sum over (year_num) |
|----------|------------|-----|---------------------|
| 2016     | 01_<18     | 5   | 21                  |
| 2016     | 02_<25     | 6   | 21                  |
| 2016     | 03_<35     | 4   | 21                  |
| 2016     | 04_<45     | 3   | 21                  |
| 2016     | 05_45+     | 3   | 21                  |
| 2017     | 01_<18     | 2   | 16                  |
| 2017     | 02_<25     | 9   | 16                  |
| 2017     | 03_<35     | 1   | 16                  |
| 2017     | 04_<45     | 3   | 16                  |
| 2017     | 05_45+     | 1   | 16                  |
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to nest the `sum()`s:

```
select year_num, age_bucket, sum(num_cust),
       sum(sum(num_cust)) over (partition by year_num)  --WORKS!!
from foo
group by year_num, age_bucket
order by 1, 2;
```

Why?  Well, the window function is not doing aggregation.  The argument needs to be an expression that can be evaluated *after* the `group by` (because this is an aggregation query).  Because `num_cust` is not a `group by` key, it needs an aggregation function.

Perhaps this is clearer if you used a subquery:

```
select year_num, age_bucket, sum_num_cust,
       sum(sum_num_cust) over (partition by year_num)
from (select year_num, age_bucket, sum(num_cust) as sum_num_cust
      from foo
      group by year_num, age_bucket
     ) ya
order by 1, 2;
```

These two queries do exactly the same thing.  But with the subquery it should be more obvious why you need the extra aggregation.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, can you explain how the window function `sum() over ()` is different from the regular `sum()` aggregate fxn? In this example, `num_cust` is not included in the group by clause, so why does it work for `sum()` but not `sum() over (partition by)`? I am not an expert so if you could explain this in the context of how the interpreter processes the `GROUP BY` with and without a window function, that would be helpful.

Comment: @Gordon Can you explain how the window function sum() over () is different from the regular sum() aggregate fxn? In this example, num_cust is not included in the group by clause, so why does it work for sum() but not sum() over (partition by)? I am not an expert so if you could explain this in the context of how the interpreter processes the GROUP BY with and without a window function, that would be helpful.