# how to avoid sum(sum()) when writing this postgres query with window functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

*Runnable query example at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ssrpQyyajYdZkkkAJBaYUp/0*

I have a postgres table of sales; each row has a `sale_id`, `product_id`, `salesperson`, and `price`.

I want to write a query that returns, for each `(salesperson, product_id)` tuple with at least one sale:

- The total of `price` for all of the sales made by that salesperson for that product (call this `product_sales`).
- The total of `price` over *all* of that salesperson's sales (call this `total_sales`).

My current query is as follows, but I feel silly writing `sum(sum(price))`.  Is there a more standard/idiomatic approach?

```
select 
  salesperson,
  product_id,
  sum(price) as product_sales,
  sum(sum(price)) over (partition by salesperson) as total_sales
from sales
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2
```

Writing `sum(price)` instead of `sum(sum(price))` yields the following error:

```
column "sales.price" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

***UPDATES***

- See [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64869155/239712) for a nice approach using a `WITH` clause. I feel like I *ought* to be able to do this without a subquery or `WITH`.
- Just stumbled on [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46612667/239712) to a different question which proposes both `sum(sum(...))` and a subquery approach. Perhaps these are the best options?

Comment: Your method is the right way to do this.  Get over your silliness.  Window functions are very powerful and that is the right syntax with aggregation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff fair enough :-)

Comment: . . I was perhaps a bit harsh.  I remember having exactly the same reaction once upon a time.  It passed in a day or two.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Common Table Expression to simplify the query and do it in two steps.

For example:

```
with 
s as (
  select 
    salesperson,
    product_id,
    sum(price) as product_sales
  from sales
  group by salesperson, product_id
)
select
  salesperson, 
  product_id,
  product_sales,
  sum(product_sales) over (partition by salesperson) as total_sales
from s
order by salesperson, product_id
```

Result:

```
 salesperson  product_id  product_sales  total_sales 
 ------------ ----------- -------------- ----------- 
 Alice        1           2000           5400        
 Alice        2           2200           5400        
 Alice        3           1200           5400        
 Bobby        1           2000           4300        
 Bobby        2           1100           4300        
 Bobby        3           1200           4300        
 Chuck        1           2000           4300        
 Chuck        2           1100           4300        
 Chuck        3           1200           4300
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ssrpQyyajYdZkkkAJBaYUp/1).

Comment: Good point, thank you! I still feel like I *ought* to be able to do this without a CTE or subquery, but your approach definitely looks more reasonable than my original code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
select * from
(
select 
  salesperson,
  product_id,
  sum(price) over(partition by salesperson,product_id) as product_sales,
  sum(price) over(partition by salesperson) as total_sales,
  row_number() over(partition by salesperson,product_id order by sale_id) as rn
from sales s
)A where rn=1
```